# Iterating through two separate panda data frames via for loop in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas

I have two panda data frames:

```
df1    df2
1      5
4      4
3      2
```

I want to create a list such that the data frames are concatenated with a colon:

```
1:5, 4:4, 3:2
```

Help from a previous question shows I can do:

```
["{}:{}".format(a, a) for a in df1]
```

which makes a list 1:1, 4:4, 3:3, but how do I do something like this:

```
["{}:{}".format(a, b) for a, b in df1, df2]
```

to create the desired result above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"df1":[1,4,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"df2":[5,4,2]})

["{}:{}".format(a, b) for a, b in zip(df1.df1, df2.df2)]
['1:5', '4:4', '3:2']
```

Comment: your solution returns this `['df1:df2']` when i run it

Comment: It depends on what `df1` and `df2` variables mean. I'll clarify in an update

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the column for each `dataframe` and the use the `zip()` function in a list comprehension to get the desired list.

```
In [46]:    
import pandas as pd
data1 = pd.DataFrame({"df1":[1,4,3]})
data2 = pd.DataFrame({"df2":[5,4,2]})  
lst = ["{}:{}".format(x,y)  for x,y in zip(data1['df1'], data2['df2'])] 


Out[46]:
['1:5', '4:4', '3:2']
```